# Sales figure from the launch of product not the year

Tags: tableau-api

At work i am stuck at a problem ... can anyone please give me some suggestion ?

My task is to get the sales figure for first and second year since the book was launched .

For Example Harry potter was launched in 10/10/2000 then the sales figure for first year 10/10/2000 - 10/10/2001 and then second year 10/10/2001 to 10/10/2002

The figures are there for one year 1/1/2010 to 1/1/2011. but how to get it for every year ... Please note that there are many books in the table.

do i have to write sql ??? please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Really hard to help if you don't show how your table is structured. You can definitely use some date calculations, but I can only be specific if I take a look at your table

Comment: SQL would the quickest way to do it. Tableau itself doesn't help. I assume you have a list of books and their launch dates. I also assume you have sales data by day/month in a separate table. What you want to do is query the sales for each book, but have the sales count from launch up to end of first year, and separately, end of second year.